# UICollectionView not auto scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So, I had a code for auto scrolling of UICollectionView(horizontal with paging enabled). It was working. Now, I updated Xcode and iOS, suddenly, the same code isn't working anymore. I literally didn't change anything else. Have someone else faced this problem too?
This collection view is inside the header reusable view.

```
func setTimer() {
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func autoScroll() {
        print("x is", self.x, self.allBanners.count)
        if self.x < self.allBanners.count {
            self.x = self.x + 1
        } else {
            self.x = 1
        }
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.resuableView.featuredCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.x, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            self.resuableView.featuredCollectionView?.setNeedsLayout()
//        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let xPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
        self.x = Int(ceil(xPosition/w))
        print("dec", self.x)
    }
```

If I print the value of x, it prints correctly. That is, after every 3 seconds, it increases by 1, but, that scrollToItem isn't working.
Also, if I disable the paging, then, it works, but, I really do need paging.
Even if I manually scroll the collection view to any item, it just reverts it back to the first item, whenever **@objc func autoScroll()** function gets called.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
P.S. I have tried this without async, with async, without or with setNeedsLayout.
I have Xcode version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

Comment: I think dispatch async to the main queue is needed, can you try by removing setNeedsLayout?

Comment: Like, I said, I have tried it all of these possible ways. I fact, the original one didn't have setNeedsLayout() or async

Comment: What is the value of `self.allBanners.count`?

Comment: That count is 6

Comment: You have this line: `self.resuableView.featuredCollectionView?.scrollToItem` ... and the `?` indicates that `featuredCollectionView` *may not be valid*. Have you stepped through in debug to make sure it is? Can you post additional code - enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes, i have. It want' even there in the first place. I was just trying this, to fix the problem. I have tried this without ?. This view is not null

Comment: @KaranveerSingh - I just tried your code with a collection view added as a subview, cell width equal to collection view width, paging enabled... and it seems to work fine. Can you put together a [mre]?

Comment: I used Storyboard and in Xcode 12.01? Did you use the same too? Although, I will check your answer too, but, for time being, I have used a workaround. I just disable paging before scrolling and then enable it after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some quirks, particularly with iOS 14...

If a cell breaks auto-layout, `scrollToItemAt` fails miserably, as well as manual scrolling.

Here is a complete example that works:

---

**Simple cell class**

```
class MyTestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var cView: UIView = UIView()
    var theLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // stylize the cell a little with a bordered-rounded-corner view inset by 8-pts
        cView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        cView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        cView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(cView)
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cView.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
        
        theLabel.textAlignment = .center
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }
}
```

---

**View controller class**

```
class AutoScrollViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var myData: [String] = []
    
    var x: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create 30 strings
        myData = (0..<30).map { "Cell \($0)" }

        // couple cells with longer text for variety
        myData[3] = "More text in cell 3"
        myData[7] = "The text in cell 7 is long enough to need to wrap onto multiple lines."

        // create a flow layout
        let f = setupFlowLayout()
        
        // create the collection view
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: f)
        
        // we want to use paging
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        // register the cell
        collectionView.register(MyTestCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        // data source and delgate
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        // add a "Tap instruction" label
        let instLabel = UILabel()
        instLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        instLabel.textAlignment = .center
        instLabel.text = "Cells will auto-advance\nevery 3 seconds.\n\nYou can also Tap here\nto jump to Cell 23"
        instLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add UI elements
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        view.addSubview(instLabel)

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        instLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain collection view Top / Leading / Trailing + 40-pts
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            // collection view Height: 160
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            
            // constrain instruction label below and centered to the collection view
            instLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            instLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor),
            instLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // for testing, add a tap recognizer to the view
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapScroll))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // set collection view item size here
        if let f = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            f.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
        }
        setTimer()
    }

    func setTimer() {
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func tapScroll() {
        self.x = 23
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.x, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func autoScroll() {
        print("x is", self.x, "Cell Count is", self.myData.count)
        self.x = self.x + 1
        if self.x >= self.myData.count {
            self.x = 0
        }
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.x, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
    }

}
```

---

**Extension with DataSource and Delegate implementation**

```
extension AutoScrollViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    private func setupFlowLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.sectionInset = .zero
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        return flowLayout
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTestCell
        // alternate cell background color so we can see it
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? .orange : .yellow
        c.theLabel.text = myData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let xPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
        self.x = Int(ceil(xPosition/w))
        print("dec", xPosition, w, self.x)
    }

}
```

---

No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections, so just assign a default `UIViewController` the custom class of `AutoScrollViewController` (from the above code).